# Running MatplotLib Python Code ImportErrors

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, interactive, line-plot

I am trying to run Randy Olson's code - Percentage of Bachelor's Degrees Conferred to Women. 
http://www.randalolson.com/2014/06/28/how-to-make-beautiful-data-visualizations-in-python-with-matplotlib/

Full Code (written by Randy Olson and not me, obviously):

```
from pandas import read_csv  

# Read the data into a pandas DataFrame.  
gender_degree_data = read_csv("http://www.randalolson.com/wp-content/uploads/percent-bachelors-degrees-women-usa.csv")  

# These are the "Tableau 20" colors as RGB.  
tableau20 = [(31, 119, 180), (174, 199, 232), (255, 127, 14), (255, 187, 120),  
             (44, 160, 44), (152, 223, 138), (214, 39, 40), (255, 152, 150),  
             (148, 103, 189), (197, 176, 213), (140, 86, 75), (196, 156, 148),  
             (227, 119, 194), (247, 182, 210), (127, 127, 127), (199, 199, 199),  
             (188, 189, 34), (219, 219, 141), (23, 190, 207), (158, 218, 229)]  

# Scale the RGB values to the [0, 1] range, which is the format matplotlib accepts.  
for i in range(len(tableau20)):  
    r, g, b = tableau20[i]  
    tableau20[i] = (r / 255., g / 255., b / 255.)  

# You typically want your plot to be ~1.33x wider than tall. This plot is a rare  
# exception because of the number of lines being plotted on it.  
# Common sizes: (10, 7.5) and (12, 9)  
figure(figsize=(12, 14))  

# Remove the plot frame lines. They are unnecessary chartjunk.  
ax = subplot(111)  
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)  
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)  
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)  
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)  

# Ensure that the axis ticks only show up on the bottom and left of the plot.  
# Ticks on the right and top of the plot are generally unnecessary chartjunk.  
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()  

# Limit the range of the plot to only where the data is.  
# Avoid unnecessary whitespace.  
ylim(0, 90)  
xlim(1968, 2014)  

# Make sure your axis ticks are large enough to be easily read.  
# You don't want your viewers squinting to read your plot.  
yticks(range(0, 91, 10), [str(x) + "%" for x in range(0, 91, 10)], fontsize=14)  
xticks(fontsize=14)  

# Provide tick lines across the plot to help your viewers trace along  
# the axis ticks. Make sure that the lines are light and small so they  
# don't obscure the primary data lines.  
for y in range(10, 91, 10):  
    plot(range(1968, 2012), [y] * len(range(1968, 2012)), "--", lw=0.5, color="black", alpha=0.3)  

# Remove the tick marks; they are unnecessary with the tick lines we just plotted.  
plt.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off",  
                labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")  

# Now that the plot is prepared, it's time to actually plot the data!  
# Note that I plotted the majors in order of the highest % in the final year.  
majors = ['Health Professions', 'Public Administration', 'Education', 'Psychology',  
          'Foreign Languages', 'English', 'Communications\nand Journalism',  
          'Art and Performance', 'Biology', 'Agriculture',  
          'Social Sciences and History', 'Business', 'Math and Statistics',  
          'Architecture', 'Physical Sciences', 'Computer Science',  
          'Engineering']  

for rank, column in enumerate(majors):  
    # Plot each line separately with its own color, using the Tableau 20  
    # color set in order.  
    plot(gender_degree_data.Year.values,  
            gender_degree_data[column.replace("\n", " ")].values,  
            lw=2.5, color=tableau20[rank])  

    # Add a text label to the right end of every line. Most of the code below  
    # is adding specific offsets y position because some labels overlapped.  
    y_pos = gender_degree_data[column.replace("\n", " ")].values[-1] - 0.5  
    if column == "Foreign Languages":  
        y_pos += 0.5  
    elif column == "English":  
        y_pos -= 0.5  
    elif column == "Communications\nand Journalism":  
        y_pos += 0.75  
    elif column == "Art and Performance":  
        y_pos -= 0.25  
    elif column == "Agriculture":  
        y_pos += 1.25  
    elif column == "Social Sciences and History":  
        y_pos += 0.25  
    elif column == "Business":  
        y_pos -= 0.75  
    elif column == "Math and Statistics":  
        y_pos += 0.75  
    elif column == "Architecture":  
        y_pos -= 0.75  
    elif column == "Computer Science":  
        y_pos += 0.75  
    elif column == "Engineering":  
        y_pos -= 0.25  

    # Again, make sure that all labels are large enough to be easily read  
    # by the viewer.  
    text(2011.5, y_pos, column, fontsize=14, color=tableau20[rank])  

# matplotlib's title() call centers the title on the plot, but not the graph,  
# so I used the text() call to customize where the title goes.  

# Make the title big enough so it spans the entire plot, but don't make it  
# so big that it requires two lines to show.  

# Note that if the title is descriptive enough, it is unnecessary to include  
# axis labels; they are self-evident, in this plot's case.  
text(1995, 93, "Percentage of Bachelor's degrees conferred to women in the U.S.A."  
       ", by major (1970-2012)", fontsize=17, ha="center")  

# Always include your data source(s) and copyright notice! And for your  
# data sources, tell your viewers exactly where the data came from,  
# preferably with a direct link to the data. Just telling your viewers  
# that you used data from the "U.S. Census Bureau" is completely useless:  
# the U.S. Census Bureau provides all kinds of data, so how are your  
# viewers supposed to know which data set you used?  
text(1966, -8, "Data source: nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/2013menu_tables.asp"  
       "\nAuthor: Randy Olson (randalolson.com / @randal_olson)"  
       "\nNote: Some majors are missing because the historical data "  
       "is not available for them", fontsize=10)  

# Finally, save the figure as a PNG.  
# You can also save it as a PDF, JPEG, etc.  
# Just change the file extension in this call.  
# bbox_inches="tight" removes all the extra whitespace on the edges of your plot.  
savefig("percent-bachelors-degrees-women-usa.png", bbox_inches="tight");
```

I have all of the dependencies as I installed Python through Anaconda. I am not sure how to run it through IPython Notebook, though, and am hoping I can work around that. I am having trouble with the imports
I have:

```
from pandas import read_csv  
from matplotlib import *
from matplotlib.figure import figure
```

But I keep getting `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` or `ImportError: cannot import name figure`

I know this is a pretty basic Python problem but I'm not sure what to do here. I want a line plot with multiple lines that has an interactive hovertool and this seems like the best example I can find. If anyone knows how to fix this or even knows of other examples of already written interactive lineplots that are easy to manipulate with new data, let me know!

EDIT:

using

```
from pandas import read_csv  
from matplotlib import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import pandas
```

and the same code:

Full Traceback

```
runfile('C:/Users/jbyrusb/Documents/Python Scripts/Disputes/WomenDegreesExample.py', wdir='C:/Users/jbyrusb/Documents/Python Scripts/Disputes')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-1b99e15a9df1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/jbyrusb/Documents/Python Scripts/Disputes/WomenDegreesExample.py', wdir='C:/Users/jbyrusb/Documents/Python Scripts/Disputes')

  File "C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\jbyrusb\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/jbyrusb/Documents/Python Scripts/Disputes/WomenDegreesExample.py", line 33, in <module>
    figure(figsize=(12, 14))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: I think you mean `from matplotlib.figure import Figure` (upper case "F")

Comment: Ah. Thanks @PaulH I changed it but am getting the TypeError still

Comment: on the same line? post the full traceback

Comment: @PaulH Posted with full traceback

Comment: So the code you posted isn't what's causing the error. It's like 33 in "WomenDegreesExample.py": `figure(figsize=(12, 14))`. I think that should also be an upper case F

Comment: Strange. Is that because things have updated since his original code? I changed it and now am getting an error on the next line for subplot. NameError: name 'subplot' is not defined @PaulH

Comment: hard to say w/o seeing a minimal example of the code. my guess is that this is just part of the perils of doing `from <package> import *`. I recommend just: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.figure()`

Comment: @PaulH sorry I forgot to clarify that the entire code is on the link I had put in the question. Anyway, I posted it so that it will be more accessible. I have a feeling I will keep getting errors down the code unless I get import all the modules properly, which is tricky as I haven't used matplotlib before.

Comment: @PaulH Anyway, adding plt. to every command using your recommendation worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example in your link calls `%pylab inline`, which an ipython command that among other things, executes`from pylab import *`.

This is literally the worst way to demonstrate matplotlib and if I could wave a magic wand and it remove it from the internet and the world, I would.

In short, adding `from pylab import *` to the top of the original code should solve the problems.

Here's the code in modern object-oriented matplotlib:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import seaborn

seaborn.set(style='white')

# Read the data into a pandas DataFrame.
url = "http://www.randalolson.com/wp-content/uploads/percent-bachelors-degrees-women-usa.csv"
gender_degree_data = pandas.read_csv(url)

# These are the "Tableau 20" colors as RGB.
tableau20 = np.array([
    ( 31, 119, 180), (174, 199, 232), (255, 127,  14), (255, 187, 120),
    ( 44, 160,  44), (152, 223, 138), (214,  39,  40), (255, 152, 150),
    (148, 103, 189), (197, 176, 213), (140,  86,  75), (196, 156, 148),
    (227, 119, 194), (247, 182, 210), (127, 127, 127), (199, 199, 199),
    (188, 189,  34), (219, 219, 141), ( 23, 190, 207), (158, 218, 229)
]) / 255.

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 14))

seaborn.despine(ax=ax, left=True, bottom=True)

ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax.yaxis.tick_left()

ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=90)
ax.set_xlim(left=1968, right=2014)


ax.set_yticks(range(0, 91, 10))
ax.set_yticklabels([str(x) + "%" for x in range(0, 91, 10)])

for y in range(10, 91, 10):
    ax.plot(range(1968, 2012), [y] * len(range(1968, 2012)), "--", 
            lw=0.5, color="black", alpha=0.3)


ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off", labelsize=14,
                labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")

majors = [
    'Health Professions', 'Public Administration', 'Education', 
    'Psychology','Foreign Languages', 'English', 
    'Communications\nand Journalism', 'Art and Performance',
    'Biology', 'Agriculture', 'Social Sciences and History', 
    'Business', 'Math and Statistics', 'Architecture',
    'Physical Sciences', 'Computer Science','Engineering'
]

offsets = {
    "Foreign Languages": +0.5,
    "English": -0.5,
    "Communications\nand Journalism": +0.75,
    "Art and Performance": -0.25,
    "Agriculture": +1.25,
    "Social Sciences and History": +0.25,
    "Business": -0.75,
    "Math and Statistics": +0.75,
    "Architecture": -0.75,
    "Computer Science": +0.75,
    "Engineering": -0.25,
}

for rank, column in enumerate(majors):
    ax.plot(gender_degree_data.Year.values,
            gender_degree_data[column.replace("\n", " ")].values,
            lw=2.5, color=tableau20[rank])

    y_pos = gender_degree_data[column.replace("\n", " ")].values[-1] - 0.5
    y_pos += offsets.get(column, 0)

    ax.text(2011.5, y_pos, column, fontsize=14, color=tableau20[rank])

ax.text(1995, 93, "Percentage of Bachelor's degrees conferred to women in the U.S.A."
       ", by major (1970-2012)", fontsize=17, ha="center")

ax.text(1966, -8, "Data source: nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/2013menu_tables.asp"
       "\nAuthor: Randy Olson (randalolson.com / @randal_olson)"
       "\nNote: Some majors are missing because the historical data "
       "is not available for them", fontsize=10)

fig.savefig("percent-bachelors-degrees-women-usa.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be some simple import command, but I had never seen %pylab inline before. Adding your suggestion worked.

Comment: I know I shouldn't use comments for this but kudos for *"and if I could remove it from the internet and the world, I would"*

Answer (score 0):

As Paul points out, using `%pylab inline` is an outdated practice and should no longer be used. Here's the updated code that can be run outside of the IPython Notebook and doesn't add the extra Seaborn dependency.

I've also written an example that uses only matplotlib. You can find it in the matplotlib gallery [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/examples/showcase/bachelors_degrees_by_gender.py).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Read the data into a pandas DataFrame.  
gender_degree_data = pd.read_csv("http://www.randalolson.com/wp-content/uploads/percent-bachelors-degrees-women-usa.csv")  

# These are the "Tableau 20" colors as RGB.  
tableau20 = [(31, 119, 180), (174, 199, 232), (255, 127, 14), (255, 187, 120),  
             (44, 160, 44), (152, 223, 138), (214, 39, 40), (255, 152, 150),  
             (148, 103, 189), (197, 176, 213), (140, 86, 75), (196, 156, 148),  
             (227, 119, 194), (247, 182, 210), (127, 127, 127), (199, 199, 199),  
             (188, 189, 34), (219, 219, 141), (23, 190, 207), (158, 218, 229)]  

# Scale the RGB values to the [0, 1] range, which is the format matplotlib accepts.  
for i in range(len(tableau20)):  
    r, g, b = tableau20[i]  
    tableau20[i] = (r / 255., g / 255., b / 255.)  

# You typically want your plot to be ~1.33x wider than tall. This plot is a rare  
# exception because of the number of lines being plotted on it.  
# Common sizes: (10, 7.5) and (12, 9)  
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 14))  

# Remove the plot frame lines. They are unnecessary chartjunk.  
ax = plt.subplot(111)  
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)  
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)  
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)  
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)  

# Ensure that the axis ticks only show up on the bottom and left of the plot.  
# Ticks on the right and top of the plot are generally unnecessary chartjunk.  
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()  
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()  

# Limit the range of the plot to only where the data is.  
# Avoid unnecessary whitespace.  
plt.ylim(0, 90)  
plt.xlim(1968, 2014)  

# Make sure your axis ticks are large enough to be easily read.  
# You don't want your viewers squinting to read your plot.  
plt.yticks(range(0, 91, 10), [str(x) + "%" for x in range(0, 91, 10)], fontsize=14)  
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)  

# Provide tick lines across the plot to help your viewers trace along  
# the axis ticks. Make sure that the lines are light and small so they  
# don't obscure the primary data lines.  
for y in range(10, 91, 10):  
    plt.plot(range(1968, 2012), [y] * len(range(1968, 2012)), "--", lw=0.5, color="black", alpha=0.3)  

# Remove the tick marks; they are unnecessary with the tick lines we just plotted.  
plt.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off",  
                labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")  

# Now that the plot is prepared, it's time to actually plot the data!  
# Note that I plotted the majors in order of the highest % in the final year.  
majors = ['Health Professions', 'Public Administration', 'Education', 'Psychology',  
          'Foreign Languages', 'English', 'Communications\nand Journalism',  
          'Art and Performance', 'Biology', 'Agriculture',  
          'Social Sciences and History', 'Business', 'Math and Statistics',  
          'Architecture', 'Physical Sciences', 'Computer Science',  
          'Engineering']  

for rank, column in enumerate(majors):  
    # Plot each line separately with its own color, using the Tableau 20  
    # color set in order.  
    plt.plot(gender_degree_data.Year.values,  
            gender_degree_data[column.replace("\n", " ")].values,  
            lw=2.5, color=tableau20[rank])  

    # Add a text label to the right end of every line. Most of the code below  
    # is adding specific offsets y position because some labels overlapped.  
    y_pos = gender_degree_data[column.replace("\n", " ")].values[-1] - 0.5  
    if column == "Foreign Languages":  
        y_pos += 0.5  
    elif column == "English":  
        y_pos -= 0.5  
    elif column == "Communications\nand Journalism":  
        y_pos += 0.75  
    elif column == "Art and Performance":  
        y_pos -= 0.25  
    elif column == "Agriculture":  
        y_pos += 1.25  
    elif column == "Social Sciences and History":  
        y_pos += 0.25  
    elif column == "Business":  
        y_pos -= 0.75  
    elif column == "Math and Statistics":  
        y_pos += 0.75  
    elif column == "Architecture":  
        y_pos -= 0.75  
    elif column == "Computer Science":  
        y_pos += 0.75  
    elif column == "Engineering":  
        y_pos -= 0.25  

    # Again, make sure that all labels are large enough to be easily read  
    # by the viewer.  
    plt.text(2011.5, y_pos, column, fontsize=14, color=tableau20[rank])  

# matplotlib's title() call centers the title on the plot, but not the graph,  
# so I used the text() call to customize where the title goes.  

# Make the title big enough so it spans the entire plot, but don't make it  
# so big that it requires two lines to show.  

# Note that if the title is descriptive enough, it is unnecessary to include  
# axis labels; they are self-evident, in this plot's case.  
plt.text(1995, 93, "Percentage of Bachelor's degrees conferred to women in the U.S.A."  
       ", by major (1970-2012)", fontsize=17, ha="center")  

# Always include your data source(s) and copyright notice! And for your  
# data sources, tell your viewers exactly where the data came from,  
# preferably with a direct link to the data. Just telling your viewers  
# that you used data from the "U.S. Census Bureau" is completely useless:  
# the U.S. Census Bureau provides all kinds of data, so how are your  
# viewers supposed to know which data set you used?  
plt.text(1966, -8, "Data source: nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/2013menu_tables.asp"  
       "\nAuthor: Randy Olson (randalolson.com / @randal_olson)"  
       "\nNote: Some majors are missing because the historical data "  
       "is not available for them", fontsize=10)  

# Finally, save the figure as a PNG.  
# You can also save it as a PDF, JPEG, etc.  
# Just change the file extension in this call.  
# bbox_inches="tight" removes all the extra whitespace on the edges of your plot.  
plt.savefig("percent-bachelors-degrees-women-usa.png", bbox_inches="tight");
```

Here's what the final result looks like:

[image]

I've updated my [blog post](http://www.randalolson.com/2014/06/28/how-to-make-beautiful-data-visualizations-in-python-with-matplotlib/) with this new code as well. Thanks for bringing this issue to my attention!